# Word processor that will create text files with embedded images, but store the images outside of the text

Tags: text-editor, git, plain-text

I've been using Microsoft Word for note-taking, and git for version control. The problem is that git can't diff the Microsoft Word files, so I'd like to switch to using a plaintext format. However, I still want to be able to paste images into my documents. I want to be able to do this easily so as not to interrupt the flow of note-taking (I'm not looking to edit HTML or something like that). I think my ideal word processor for this kind of task would display a document with text and images, but actually store the file as plaintext with links to the images and store the images separately. Is there a program that would work for this use case?

Comment: Actually I found a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840231/what-is-the-most-git-friendly-documentation-format so there's no need to answer unless you know of something better than Markdown or RTF

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor (free, cross platform) allows this. Using plugin "Insert Pics".

- Install plugin from menu: Plugins / Addon Manager / Install, enter "insert pics".
- Call plugin commands from menu: Plugins / Insert Pics.
- Readme is at https://github.com/CudaText-addons/cuda_insert_pics/tree/master/readme

Example screenshot of text with pictures:

[image: Insert Pics plugin]